# Edit and Continue doesn't work (C++, Visual Studio Community 2015)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015, edit-and-continue

Visual Studio 2015 never applies my code changes when I break, make a code change, then continue.

It gives me this message in the Output window:

```
-------- Edit and Continue build started --------

--------------------- Done ----------------------

Edit and Continue : Successfully applied code changes.
```

It lies; it didn't apply anything. If a set a breakpoint in that file again, it tells me:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version.
```

I can't find any incorrect compiler flags, and Edit and Continue is enabled in the options:

[image]

I've used Edit and Continue a lot in VS 2005 and 2010 and it worked just fine. (Well, it worked more than 0% of the time at least.) What's going on in 2015?

Comment: Can you try unchecking "Allow precompiling (Native only)" and ensuring that "Require source files to exactly match the original version" is checked?

Comment: @Ramkumar "Require source files to exactly match..." is checked. I tried unchecking "Allow precompiling (Native only)" and it did not help.

Comment: I see. Is this specific to your project or does it happen even with a hello world Win32 Console App? Also, if you haven't already, could you try installing Update 3?

Comment: @Ramkumar Update 3 appears to have fixed it.

Comment: Awesome, glad that's fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now after installing Update 3.